# How should I add web components to a page?

Tags: web-component

I have a component `<search-select>` that uses 2 other web components inside - `<autocomplete-input>` and `<autocomplete-dropdown>`.
Right now I add them all in the index.html like that:

```
<script src="./components/selection/SearchSelect.js"></script>
<script src="./components/selection/Autocomplete-input.js"></script>
<script src="./components/selection/Autocomplete-dropdown.js"></script>
```

But should I add those 2 `<autocomplete-...>` components inside their parent (like you do in React or Vue) and not in the index.html next to their parent? If so then how do I do that?

Comment: Contrary to framework components   it doesn't matter when or where you define native javascript web components

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman so how do I import autocomplete component into search-select component? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Your code is fine. The **order** doesn't matter. And it doesn't matter **when** or **where** a script is loaded. (because, for now, all goes the global CustomElementsRegistry) **Provided** you coded a _good_ Web Component. If you have coded dependencies between Web Components (like A MUST exist before B is defined/upgraded/connected) you have coded a Web Component that, pardon the language, just sucks. Note that "Framework" Components can not do that order/when/where magic.

Answer (score 1):

The load **order** doesn't matter. And it doesn't matter **when** or (from) **where** a script is loaded.
All native Web Components end up in the global CustomElementsRegistry.
*(we might get **scoped** registries in the future)*

Below `<my-component>` is an [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement)
(Still a child of HTMLElement! So you can treat it like any HTMLElement)

Once you click; the Element is **defined** and thus **"upgrades"** all existing instances.
**anywhere** in the DOM or shadowDOMs

This modern JS magic is something **no** oldskool React, Vue, Angular or Svelte Component can do.
In Frameworks you must *define* before you can *use* a component. Just like Variables.

JSWC1

```js
document.onclick = (evt) => {
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = "Yeah! I am defined now!";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
my-component:not(:defined) {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

my-component:defined {
  background: green;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<my-component>Hello World!</my-component>
```

Note: There are Framework libraries that replicate Component "upgrade" behaviour; but since they run in the ***JavaScript* Engine**, they will never achieve modern JS performance, which does the magic in the ***Browser* Engine**.